# Group a single column with letter and name in datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can we have letter and name grouping for a single column using [rowGrouping](https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/) plug-in and jQuery DataTables?

Eg: For values:

```
aaa=>1,aaa=>2,aaa=>3,aab=>1,aab=>2,aab=>3,aac=>1,aac=>2,...
```

should group (`sGroupBy`) with letter `A`, `B`, then with name `aaa`, `aab`, `aac`.

Answer (score 2):

> **SOLUTION**

Plug-in [rowGrouping](https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com) is no longer being developed, I would not recommend using it. Use alternative way to perform row grouping as shown in [Row grouping example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html).

For example, use the code below to group rows by first letter when sorted by column containing names.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "drawCallback": function (settings){
        var api = this.api();

        // Zero-based index of the column containing names
        var col_name = 0;

        // If ordered by column containing names
        if (api.order()[0][0] === col_name) {
            var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
            var group_last = null;

            api.column(col_name, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (name, index){
                var group = name.substr(0, 1);

                if (group_last !== group) {
                    $(rows).eq(index).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="6">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                    );

                    group_last = group;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w10m41j5/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Yes, let us get rid of those buggy 1.9.x plugins!