# Column filter is not working with row grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I integrate jQuery DataTables [column filter](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/) and [row grouping](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-grouping/), jQuery DataTables column filter is not working.

I tried the [demo](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn-history/r71/trunk/rowGrouping.html) but it seems in the demo column filter also does not work.

Comment: see answer here -> [**Group a single column with letter and name in datatable?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32693441/1407478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Plug-ins [Row Grouping](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-grouping/) along with [Column Filtering](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/) are no longer being developed, I would not recommend using them. Use DataTables options and API methods to perform row grouping and individual column searching as shown in [Row grouping example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html) and [Individual column searching example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html).

```js
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "order": [[2, 'asc']],
    "drawCallback": function (settings){
        var api = this.api();

        // Zero-based index of the column for row grouping
        var col_name = 2;

        // If ordered by column containing names
        if (api.order()[0][0] === col_name) {
            var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
            var group_last = null;

            api.column(col_name, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (name, index){
                var group = name;

                if (group_last !== group) {
                    $(rows).eq(index).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="6">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                    );

                    group_last = group;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pu0avv0/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I having problems. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030151/responsive-display-object-object-in-datatables) 
Please help me

Comment: I want to ask again.  I want to change Plug-ins Row Grouping with API methods to perform row grouping. Previously, i use Plug-ins Row Grouping([link](http://jsfiddle.net/rkovmhkp/4/)).  If using API model, how to take color field from database. Thank you

Comment: @mosestoh, the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkovmhkp/4/) shows that color is taken from 5th column of each row. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I know it. But I still have difficulty when using API methods. When using API methods, I can not take the color field

Comment: I try like this : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/5jccbzdy/1/). From the test variable can be taken the color field, but I still have difficulty.