# fnRowCallback in rowGrouping is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My code is like this :

```
    ... 

    .rowGrouping({
                bExpandableGrouping: false,
                iGroupingColumnIndex: 2,
                bHideGroupingColumn: true,
                asExpandedGroups: [""],

                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {                  
                      $("td.group").css({
                           "background-color": aData.colour,
                      });
                }
    });

    ...
```

I need `fnRowCallback` because I want to get the `colour` parameter. But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762340/3549014) to your other question about row grouping. In general, **it is no longer recommended to use Row Grouping plug-in**.

It doesn't work for you because `fnRowCallback` is option for jQuery DataTables plug-in not Row Grouping plugin, see [list of options](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-grouping/wiki/Options)  for Row Grouping plug-in.

> **SOLUTION**

Use CSS rule to target rows with class `.group`

```
.dataTable tr.group {
   background-color:#CCC;
}
```

If you need to set grouping row color dynamically, you can use `fnOnGrouped` callback that is called when grouping is completed, analyze groups and color them appropriately.

```
fnOnGrouped: function(groups){
    console.log("Groups", groups);

    for(key in groups){
       if(groups.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           $(groups[key].nGroup).css('background-color', '#F99');
       }
    }                   
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkovmhkp/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. The color is taken from the database. Each group has a different color. It need a parameter to call the color field. I still difficult to call the color fields of a database

Comment: fnOnGrouped has no parameter. So, I still difficult to call the color fields of a database

Comment: @mosestoh, see the demo and check the console. `fnOnGrouped` receives a list of groups as a parameter.

Comment: I know fnOnGrouped receives a list of groups as a parameter. But I still have difficulty using it to call field color from database

Comment: How to call color field from database? I have not yet found it.

Comment: @mosestoh, it's not clear where color is specified in your data, you need to post your JSON data to clarify.

Comment: Ok. I use codeigniter framework. Controller : [link](http://pastebin.com/rW5CxbJm). View : [link](http://pastebin.com/UJyD8y72). I use fnCreatedCell. But, it's not working.

Comment: @mosestoh, you can use `fnCreatedCell` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkovmhkp/2/)) or better yet `fnCreatedRow` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkovmhkp/3/)) but it will color rows other than grouping rows.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I just want to color grouping rows. I want to set grouping row color dynamically. So, the color is taken from the database.  Each grouping row has a different color. This is my difficulty. Sorry, my english is not so good

Comment: I try :  `"fnOnGrouped": function(groups){
                for(key in groups){
                    if(groups.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                        $(groups[key].nGroup).css('background-color', groups.colour);
                    }
                }       
            }` . But it's not wokring. This needs a parameter to get color

Comment: This is so difficult. To this day, I have not found a solution.

Comment: @mosestoh, it's not that difficult, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkovmhkp/4/) if you want to use row data to color grouping row.

Comment: I want to ask again. I want to add row grouping menu and no row grouping menu. If user click row grouping menu, the system will display datatables row grouping. If user click no row grouping menu, the system will display datatables without row grouping. What  can be done? Thank you

Comment: @mosestoh, please ask a new question and I will try to help.

Comment: Ok. I will ask a new question

Comment: My new querstion : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827360/how-to-add-checkbox-in-datatables-for-row-grouping). Sorry, my english is not so good